# Responsive content slider sometime cuts too much of the bottom off images

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

http://1aproductions.ots-internet3.net

So my wordless theme has a built in slider. It is responsive. The slider is in the background and seems to have a height of 100%. On browsers that are normal width but tall this means that a lot of the image is hidden behind the white background of the content lower down the page. If you resize the page while the slider is on the slide image of the queen you will see why this is a problem. My boss would like it to always show her heard and shoulders.

Is there a way of, on longer shaped browser windows, stopping the image from being 100% height and therefore making it display better on longer height browsers as well as normal shaped ones?

As you can probably tell I'm kind of out of my depth on this one, so any help would be fantastic!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily for you there is a quick fix on this particular slider. The elements are set to have  a background-attachment of `fixed` on `#slider-container .full-bg-image`. Clear it and the whole picture will display. You should then be able to use the background-position to align more specifically for mobile, or only have the fixed position for desktop use with a media query. I'm not sure what method the powers that be would like best :)